# How to check TestNG Assert.assertEqual() conditional checking

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

Let me explain what I exactly expecting 
I have a method like the following

```
public void  removeByObject()
{
try {
            DsrCollection dsrCollection = new DsrCollection();
            dsrCollection. setNuId(180);
            dsrCollectionRepository.remove(dsrCollection);
}
catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here I want to check that the particular method removeByObject() executed successfully or not(also want to involve **Assert.assertEqual(dsrCollectionRepository.remove(dsrCollection),??))**. So for checking the condition what should be the actual value.

Or in a more specific way what object should appear in actual value place. My requirement is like if application failed to execute dsrCollectionRepository.remove(dsrCollection) it should return the assertError message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `removeByObject()` more testable you can simply extract the code in the `try` block into its own method. e.g.:

```
public class DsrCollectionRepositoryManager /* Or whatever your class is called. */ {
    /* ... */

    public void removeByObject() {
        try {
            removeByObjectOrThrow();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected boolean /* or whatever your return type is */ removeByObjectOrThrow() {
        DsrCollection dsrCollection = new DsrCollection();
        dsrCollection.setNuId(180);
        return dsrCollectionRepository.remove(dsrCollection);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Now you can test `removeByObjectOrThrow()` and see if it throws an exception or not.

If you are trying to test it where `removeByObject()` is called on your behalf and/or you don't want to call `removeByObjectOrThrow()` directly then you can subclass your unit under test. e.g.:

```
public class DsrCollectionRepositoryManagerTest {
    @Test
    public void removeObjectSuccessful() {
        boolean expected = true;
        DsrCollectionRepositoryManager dsrCollectionRepositoryManager = new DsrCollectionRepositoryManager() {
            @Override
            protected boolean removeByObjectOrThrow() {
                try {
                    boolean actual = super.removeByObjectOrThrow();
                    Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
                    return actual;
                } catch (Exception cause) {
                    String message = "`removeObject` should not have thrown an exception but did";
                    throw new AssertionError(message, cause);
                }
            }
        };
        dsrCollectionRepositoryManager.removeByObject();
    }

    @Test
    public void removeObjectUnsuccessful() {
        DsrCollectionRepositoryManager dsrCollectionRepositoryManager = new DsrCollectionRepositoryManager() {
            @Override
            protected boolean removeByObjectOrThrow() {
                super.removeByObjectOrThrow();
                String detailMessage = "`removeByObject` should have thrown an exception but did not";
                throw new AssertionError(detailMessage);
            }
        };
        dsrCollectionRepositoryManager.removeByObject();
    }
}
```

As I don't know the name of your unit under test nor the type of what you want to use `assertEquals` with I've made things up but the idea is the same: isolate the code you want to test and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Does dsrCollectionRepository.remove(obj) return a value indicating whether the removal is successful or not? I'd recommend implementing the function so it does return a boolean on a successful removal of an object, otherwise you rely on exceptions to inform you of the failure of the function.

If it already returns a boolean value just `assertTrue(dsrCollectionRepository.remove(dsrCollection);`

If the failure of the function throws a known exception you can use the following annotation to test the function:
`@Test(expectedExceptions = MyException.class)`, however you then rely on the fact that only that exception can be thrown while performing that function, which is problematic if someone adds an exception that can be thrown in implementation without your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the ans but dsrCollectionRepository.remove(dsrCollection) does not return any boolean value. and If I change the return type of remove() then it cause change the base model repository implementation. Which is not accepted. So do you have any other suggestion in this regard

Comment: Can you do a check on the dsrCollectionRepository  to see if the object is still there? Like a .isPresent or .hasObject function?